# Ring Isomorphism of Subfield to Matrix Space

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let K be a subfield of a field L, which can be treated as an n-dimensional K-vector space (n < $\infty$). Show that L is isomorphic as a ring to a subring of $M_n(K)$.

I can't figure out what isomorphism makes sense.

Comment: Hint: For each $\alpha\in L$, the map $L\to L$ defined by $x\mapsto \alpha\cdot x$ is a $K$-linear map.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$. For each $l\in L$, there is a $K$-linear map $m_l:x\in L\mapsto lx\in L$. This gives us a function $\phi:l\in L\mapsto m_l\in\operatorname{End}_K(L)$.

Show this $\phi$ is an injective morphism of rings.

Finally —and only if you insist in matrices— pick a basis of $L$ as a $K$-vector space, and use it to define a ring isomorphism $\operatorname{End}_K(L)\to M_n(K)$, and consider the composition off $\phi$ with this.